# Do I need a slim or normal polarized filter for a wide angle lens?

Tags: filters, digital, landscape, wide-angle, polarizer

I have a Canon T3i body and I recently bought a Tokina 11-16mm wide angle lens for landscape and astro-photography. I am looking to buy a polarizing filter, but I'm not sure if I should get the slim or the normal filter? I might need to attach another filter to it, so will it be stackable or not? I'm looking at the Hoya filter as it is within my budget.

Also, is the Cokin filter good for quality pics? I'm also considering getting the Cokin ND cheap gradual color filters, are they worth buying? Should I get the Cokin or any other ND filter type? Can you please recommend one for me?

I'm interested in landscape, waterfalls and so on.

Comment: btw, you asked two very different questions in one post. I answered the first one.

Comment: I'd say you need neither. Polarizers are a terrible idea on ultra-wide lenses because they give terrible results.

Comment: @Itai - They give terrible results when photographing the _sky_. You can use CPLs for other purposes that are less impacted by the undesirable effect they cause with the sky. I still use them for example when shooting a waterfall in the woods, to see through the river.

Comment: you can make good sky photos as well. Just experiment how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular polarizing filter - slim or regular?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77568/circular-polarizing-filter-slim-or-regular)

Answer (score 2):

For lenses that wide you do need the slim profile filters such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FQC1OG). Luckily for you it is half price these days. I bought it back in 2009 when it was full price...

I use that on my Sigma 10-20mm without vignetting. But I doubt you can attach yet another slim filter to it, without taking a vignette hit.

Cheaper option: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Kenko-77mm-Pro1-Digital-Wide-Band-Circular-PL-CPL-W-LPF-Filter-/120962042111

Comment: @ Michael, I saw the filter, it looks  nice yet, it is a bit expensive for my budget, is there another one mid-range?

Comment: thank you a lot, yes this one is cheaper, also what about the ND filters, should I get a fixed one or variable? and what kind do you recommend?thank you for the info.good day.

Comment: gradual are very situational, so get a optically good 3-4 stop ND (ie not the cheapest which have colour tints). I dont use these because I don't like the milky water effect people use them for.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info, but which kind you recommend me to go for the ND filter? Hoya,Tiffen, Polaride or any other recommendations with mid range  price.thanks a lot.

Comment: Hoya is a good budget brand, and it is made by Tokina, like your lens. Dont go for the cheapest line. The pro1 line is pretty good for the price, and their ND pro1 is low profile. tiffen is probably the worst.

Comment: thank you for the info, I had a llok on the filters you mentioned and they look great, appreciate your help.:)

Comment: how about voting me up? :

Comment: @ Michael I tried before you ask but it asks me to have at least 15 reputations, sorry. :(, but I would love to

Answer (score 0):

As to ND fitlers, Cokins are usable, but the ones I used to own had a slight color cast. You may want to take a look at Lee filters as well. I have found the latter to be much closer to actually be neutral. While Lee and Cokin (P) filters are interchangeable, Lee holders seem to be quite a bit more expensive.

If you consider gradual ND filters, having a filter that you can shift is a great help. Screw-in filters are pretty limiting as you can not position the filter vertically.